# Silence Quiet Audio Sections Using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, noise-reduction

I would like to silence silent audio passages -- noise suppression -- using ffmpeg on the go. That is: Inject silence when the volume is below x dB (the perfection would be a smooth transition).

I had a look at [`silenceremove`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) and [`silencedetect`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect) but that either cuts or requires a multi-step process.

I also had a look at the [`dcshift`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dcshift) filter but that led nowhere as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: See the agate filter - http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#agate

Comment: @Gyan Awesome! That does it! Thank you so much!